# Saving video with overlay of GIF image

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-capture, avplayerlayer

I am working on an application in which I record a video. When recording finished I put a GIF image on it with use of  [Library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif).

My code for playing video and putting gif image as an overlay

```
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.urlstring];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    videoLayer.frame = self.preview_view.bounds;
    videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self.preview_view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];


    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"02" withExtension:@"gif"];
    self.img_gif.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

But now I want to merge and save video with overlay of this GIF image. I google it didn't find what I want.

Thank you for your help

[image: GIF image]

Comment: screen recording may help you.. When you play Video with overlay GIF start screen recording from code....

Comment: do let me know if you Idea works for you... I will help you to code for screen recording...

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Help me with it

Comment: Pl. check my answer there are several option for screen recording.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the best answer to merge video with GIF image.

```
- (void)mixVideoAsset:(AVAsset *)videoAsset {


    NSDate * begin = [NSDate date];

    // 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
    AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    // 3 - Video track
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                        ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    // - Audio
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioCompositionTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    [audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    // 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);

    // 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
        isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
        isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
        videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
    }
    [videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoAsset.duration];

    // 3.3 - Add instructions
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

    CGSize naturalSize;
    if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
    } else {
        naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
    }

    float renderWidth, renderHeight;
    renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
    renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    // Watermark Layers
    [self applyVideoEffectsToComposition:mainCompositionInst size:naturalSize];

    // 4 - Get path
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
//    NSURL * url = TempVideoURL();

    // 5 - Create exporter
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSDate * endDate = [NSDate date];
            NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:begin];
            NSLog(@"completed %f senconds",interval);

            ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            if ([assetsLibrary videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:exporter.outputURL]) {
                [assetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:exporter.outputURL completionBlock:NULL];
            }
        });
    }];

}


- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:(CGSize)size
{

    // - set up the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];

    size.width = 100;
    size.height = 100;

    // - set up the overlay
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, size.width, size.height);

    NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"jiafei" withExtension:@"gif"];
    [self startGifAnimationWithURL:fileUrl inLayer:overlayLayer];

    //    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gifImage.gif"];
    //    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[image CGImage]];
    //    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

    // - apply magic
    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

}

- (void)startGifAnimationWithURL:(NSURL *)url inLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    CAKeyframeAnimation * animation = [self animationForGifWithURL:url];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
}

- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)animationForGifWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];

    NSMutableArray * frames = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *delayTimes = [NSMutableArray new];

    CGFloat totalTime = 0.0;
    CGFloat gifWidth;
    CGFloat gifHeight;

    CGImageSourceRef gifSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url, NULL);

    // get frame count
    size_t frameCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(gifSource);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
        // get each frame
        CGImageRef frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(gifSource, i, NULL);
        [frames addObject:(__bridge id)frame];
        CGImageRelease(frame);

        // get gif info with each frame
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(gifSource, i, NULL));
        NSLog(@"kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary %@", [dict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary]);

        // get gif size
        gifWidth = [[dict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] floatValue];
        gifHeight = [[dict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] floatValue];

        // kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary中kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime，kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime值是一样的
        NSDictionary *gifDict = [dict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
        [delayTimes addObject:[gifDict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]];

        totalTime = totalTime + [[gifDict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime] floatValue];

        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(dict));
    }

    if (gifSource) {
        CFRelease(gifSource);
    }

    NSMutableArray *times = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    CGFloat currentTime = 0;
    NSInteger count = delayTimes.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(currentTime / totalTime)]];
        currentTime += [[delayTimes objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    }

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        [images addObject:[frames objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    animation.keyTimes = times;
    animation.values = images;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.duration = totalTime;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    return animation;
}
```

Comment: Pefect answer :)

Comment: It is 2020, still works. I will try to convert it into swift.

Comment: @AsifHabib have you been able to convert it to Swift?

Comment: Yes, I have converted it into swift.

Comment: @AsifHabib would you mind sharing it as an answer if possible?

Comment: @AsifHabib Yes, please share the swift version

Comment: @AsifHabib +1 please share swift version

Comment: Hey Jitender, can you help me with an issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575445/avexportsession-add-uiview-with-gifs-and-drawings-on-a-video?noredirect=1#comment115940353_65575445

Answer (score 3):

Here is the swift version of @Jitendra Modi's answer and it worked like a charm.

**Swift 5.2:**

```
    func animationForGif(with url: URL) -> CAKeyframeAnimation? {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.contents))
        
        var frames: [CGImage] = []
        var delayTimes: [CGFloat] = []
        
        var totalTime: CGFloat = 0.0
//        var gifWidth: CGFloat, gifHeight: CGFloat
        
        guard let gifSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else {
            print("Can not get image source from the gif: \(url)")
            
            return nil
        }
        
        // get frame
        let frameCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(gifSource)
        
        for i in 0..<frameCount {
            guard let frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(gifSource, i, nil) else {
                continue
            }
            
            guard let dic = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(gifSource, i, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any] else { continue }
//            gifWidth = dic[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as? CGFloat ?? 0
//            gifHeight = dic[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as? CGFloat ?? 0
            
            guard let gifDic: [AnyHashable: Any] = dic[kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary] as? [AnyHashable: Any] else { continue }
            let delayTime = gifDic[kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime] as? CGFloat ?? 0
            
            frames.append(frame)
            delayTimes.append(delayTime)
            
            totalTime += delayTime
        }
        
        if frames.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        
        assert(frames.count == delayTimes.count)
        
        var times: [NSNumber] = []
        var currentTime: CGFloat = 0
        
        for i in 0..<delayTimes.count {
            times.append(NSNumber(value: Double(currentTime / totalTime)))
            currentTime += delayTimes[i]
        }
        
        animation.keyTimes = times
        animation.values = frames
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        animation.duration = Double(totalTime)
        animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        
        animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        return animation
    }
```

And you can use this animation:

```
let gifLayer = CALayer()
gifLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)

if let animation = animationForGif(with: gifUrl) {
    gifLayer.add(animation, forKey: "contents")
}
            
parentLayer.addSublayer(gifLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the below code for Screen Recording. It will merger your video and GIF.

You can download sample from the link below provided by Apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

Hope this help you..

Comment: Yeah, I tried but new issue is coming like if user doesnt want to see whole preview and stops in between so,Video recording stops

Comment: yes User have to finish up to the end...  you need force user to complete whole video...

Comment: Second issue is that It affecting my video quality. Screen recording isn't like live video recording. SO, THNX but this is not working for me

Comment: you can use background video merge... try below SO link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694975/video-merging-in-background-ios