# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to add animated GIF file at Video using AVMutableComposition (AVFoundation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to add animated GIF file at Video file. I have GIF and Video files in Xcode.

**Reference:** [Saving video with overlay of GIF image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784040/saving-video-with-overlay-of-gif-image)

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in method **'animationForGifWithURL'** at line as shown in attached image.

Please help, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `CFRelease...` just before the error?

Comment: I think it is used for releasing memory of dictionary (dict).

Comment: iOS since iOS4 uses Automatic Reference Counting, so there's no need to manually release a NSDictionary. Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, now it works.